# SelectBoxIt & hidden layers

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to use SelectBoxIt by Greg Franko.
I want the select boxes to be hidden, until user clicks 'more option', then these selectboxes will appear. Here's the problem. When the selectboxes appear, the width is all shrunken. However, when i load the page with the 'more options' layer open, the selectboxes appear in the correct width. any idea how to get the selectboxes appear in correct width?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8>
      <title>SelectBoxIt demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.3.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="btn_moreoptions2">MORE OPTIONS <img src="images/ic_arrow_down.gif" border="0"></div>
      <div id="moreoptions2"  style="display:none;">
        234
      <select name="test">
        <option value="SelectBoxIt is:">SelectBoxIt is:</option>
        <option value="a jQuery Plugin">a jQuery Plugin</option>
        <option value="a Select Box Replacement">a Select Box Replacement</option>
        <option value="a Stateful UI Widget">a Stateful UI Widget</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.3.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          $("#btn_moreoptions2").click(function(){
            $("#moreoptions2").slideToggle();

    });
          var selectBox = $("select").selectBoxIt();

        });
      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone else also reported this issue: https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/issues/149

Here are two possible solutions:

1. When you make the SelectBoxIt drop down visible, call the SelectBoxIt `refresh()` method to rebuild the drop down.  Since the element will now be visible, the dimensions logic will work correctly.  You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJzhV/2/)
2. Use a static width (that can be set in your CSS) instead of relying on SelectBoxIt's dynamic *auto width*.  To set a static width, set the `autoWidth` option to false.  Like this:
   `$("select").selectBoxIt({ autoWidth: false });`  You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJzhV/3/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Greg Franko, however that only seems to work for the first selectbox in the 'more options' div. i need multiple, any idea?

Comment: @SuGin Could you create a test page of it not working on jsbin or jsfiddle?  I'd gladly help if I could more easily debug it.

Comment: it would seem that if the hidden div were above the visible select, the first select would work. but the rest wouldn't. if the hidden div were below the visible select, non of them would work. or am i missing something here?

Comment: I am going to provide a fix for this very soon.  I am hoping to get a new SelectBoxIt release out today which should fix it, so I will let you know when you should update.

Comment: This issue should now be fixed with the latest SelectBoxIt release!